# Libev related error when installing gevent

Tags: python-3.x, pip, gevent

I am trying to install the Python package gevent with `pip3 install gevent`; the OS is Amazon Linux 2. The installation starts, but then at some point it stops with this error:

```
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '(cd  "/tmp/pip-build-mqpe4eb2/gevent/deps/libev"  && sh ./configure -C > configure-output.txt )' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

Some months ago it used to work, which is why my first thought was the error might be related to a recent version release. However, installing an older version with `pip3 install gevent==20.04.0` resulted in the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have same problem , just upgrade the `pip` using following command has resolved

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip
pip3 install --upgrade setuptools
```

Comment: did not work for me :(